# Unescaping / decoding a string with a + in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html that is output by PHP's urlencode - basically it's a simple bunch of anchors that look like this:

```
<a href="#i+have+some+spaces">link1</a>
```

I'm using jquery to take a look at all these references when they're clicked, however, I can't seem to decode it using any of the browser's internal functions.  Do I have to replace +'s by myself?

```
unescape('Video+Games');    // returns Video+Games
decodeURI('Video+Games');   // returns Video+Games
decodeURIComponent('Video+Games');  // returns Video+Games
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do think you need to do your own `.replace()`, as in:

```
href.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
```

---

**EDIT:** I thought I had a MDC document that specified this, but the closest I can find right now is this note.

https://developer.mozilla.org/Talk:en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

I may have been thinking of this note from the [MDC encodeURIComponent docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

> For application/x-www-form-urlencoded  (POST), per http: //www.w3.org/TR/html401/interac...m-content-type, spaces are to be replaced by '+', so one may wish to follow a encodeURIComponent replacement with an additional replacement of "%20" with "+".